# New Application Best Practices Only DateTimeOffset or combination with UTC datetime2

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

so I am building a new Application and thinking what DateTime Type should I use for the values.

Imageing the follwing Item

```
Deadline
Name : string
CreationDateTime : DateTime
LastModificationDateTime : DateTime
Deadline : Date
```

Now my first thought is I just save everything as UTC datetime2, this works well for CreationDateTime and LastModificationDate, since they are set by the server. Now the Problem is Deadline. Deadline is Date.

Now the Deadline can be a Deadline-Date for China, or a Date for Germany. Now if I would display Chinese Deadline in Germany I would present to the user instead of 2. January, 1 January 18:00.

Now I am thinking if I should store all Dates as DateTimeOffset and all DateTimes as UTC-DateTime2.

My question is now: If I want to make joins or comparisons do I get problems when I compare datetime2 with datetimeoffset.

```
select * from Deadline where CreationDateUtc > @DateTimeOffsetVal
```

Also to consider: **I am in Germany and most applications here store their values in local time**. So converting everything to UTC can be tedious and erro prone. Is DateTimeOffset here an advantage?

**TL;DR My questions:**
- So should I use a combination of DateTime2 and DateTimeOffset or everything DateTimeOffset?

- Is there a performance pentality between DateTimeOffset vs datetime2? I think not?
- If using DateTimeOffset, should I use for CreationDateTime the utc time. Or the local time of the server?

Greetings
Michael

Comment: I fail to see why you wouldn't simply use Date for the deadline.  It has no time component.

Comment: We have a German User, he has to fulfill a deadline till 2. April at Midnight in China. So he enters 2. April in the Date field. But if the German User Fullfills the Deadline till 2.April Midnight in Germany he Missed it since China is 6 Hours ahead. 

But the German User also doesn't want to select 2.April 18:00.

So he has a Date Control where by default his time Zone is selected and he can select another Time Zone then the Date Field is this Date in that time Zone